# Llamar metodo php con ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, mvc

estoy haciendo una app de control de finanzas. Necesito hacer un ajax hacia un metodo de php, este es el ajax que hice, este se encuentra en app/views/egresos/addInformacionEgreso.php .

```
function addInformation (contenedor, id) {
    $.ajax({
        url:"egresos/addInformacionEgreso.php",
        type: "GET",
        dataType:'text',
        data:{data: 'AddInformacionEgreso'},
        success:function(data){
            console.log(data)
            $(contenedor).append(data);
            id = id+1;
            return id;
        }
    });
}
```

Aca dejo el metodo a llamar.

```
<?php
function AddInformacionEgreso(){ 
  $CATEGORIAS_MODEL = new categoriasModel();
  $listadoCategorias=$CATEGORIAS_MODEL->consultar();
  
  $options = '';
    for ($i=0; $i < count($listadoCategorias); $i++) { 
      $options .= "<option value='".($i+1)."'>".$listadoCategorias[$i]->nombre."</option>";
    }
  echo "<div class='input-group mb-3 mt-3' id='lista_$id'>
          <select class='form-select' id='selectCategories_$id' onChange='categories('selectCategories_$id','$id')'>
              <option value='0' selected> Categorias...</option> 
              $options
          </select>
          <input type='number' name='price' class='form-control' placeholder='Price'>

          <input type='hidden' name='item_existe[]'> 
          
          <div class='input-group mb-3 mt-3'>
              <input class='form-control' name='item[]' id='item_$id' type='text' placeholder='Search..'>
              <button type='button' onclick='generarItem('$contenedor',".($i+1).",".($i+1).")'
               id='buttonItems' class='btn btn-outline-secondary'>+</button>
          </div>
          <ul id='item-list_$id' class='list-group'></ul>
      </div>";
}

?>
```

La funcion ajax se ejecuta cuando doy click en el checkbox. pero el problema es que se muestra otra vista.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Muchas gracias por la ayuda!

Disculpen, aca dejo donde llamo a la funcion, al hacer click en el checkbox deberia mostrar el select que deberia traer el ajax.[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola. En el código PHP no muestras qué haces con los datos que recibes desde Ajax. Puede que estés llamando a otra cosa y por eso se muestra otro contenido. Pulsa en [edit] y agrega la parte donde recibes la petición y pasas los datos a la función.

Comment: Ahi agregue la parte donde se ejecutaria la funcion! me olvide de subirla. basicamente es un checkbox y al hacer click deberia mostrar el select que trae el ajax

Comment: El código siempre como texto, es más fácil para ti: copiar / pegar, y también para nosotros para analizarlo y/o reproducir el problema. Dicho eso, no me refería al código Javascript, sino a tu código `addInformacionEgreso.php`. Sólo muestras una función, pero, ¿dónde recibes el `$_GET` en `.php` y cómo llamas luego a la función? Es eso lo que quiero ver.

Comment: Creo que estoy un poco mareado, no tengo ningun $_GET. Necesito que se imprima en pantalla el echo del select de addInformacionEgreso.php. Por lo que me dijeron bastaba con usar ajax y pasarle por url el archivo php para que se ejecute la misma y se imprima en la vista. Seguro que es error mio, te pido disculpas de antemano. No entiendo bien el uso de ajax

Comment: Ajax te pasa los datos al archivo que pongas en su parámetro `url`, que en este caso es `egresos/addInformacionEgreso.php`. ¿Qué tienes en ese archivo `.php` sólo la función que nos estás mostrando? En ese archivo, debes recibir los datos enviados desde Ajax en la super global `$_GET` y usarlos para lo que necesites hacer en el servidor. No veo qué uso haces de `$_GET` en tu archivo `.php`. Que yo sepa, el hecho de poner esto `data:{data: 'AddInformacionEgreso'}` no te va a llamar automáticamente la función del `.php` o no ser que uses algún framework que haga eso...

Comment: La idea en si era esa. llamar a la funcion addInformacionEgreso.php para que muestre el listado de categorias en la vista, Y deberia hacerlo en php para que se ejecute antes que el JS. Queria usar ajax para pasar esa funcion y que muestre el listado cuando haga click en checkbox. como podre solucionarlo?

Comment: Dame unos minutos, te escribo una respuesta.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ajax sirve para pasar datos del cliente (Javascript) al servidor (PHP en este caso).

- El archivo de servidor que recibirá esos datos, los procesará y emitirá una respuesta se indica en el parámetro **`url`** de la petición Ajax. Debes asegurarte que la ruta que pones es correcta con respecto a donde se encuentra el archivo que hace la llamada Ajax.
- Los datos que pasas son indicados en el parámetro **`data`** de la petición Ajax. Aquí sólo pasas un valor asociado a una clave `data`, pero lo deseable es pasar otros valores, por ejemplo el `id` de un cliente, el `nombre` de un país, etc. En el parámetro `data` puedes pasar todo los valores que necesites. **Me refiero al parámetro por fuera** ya que desgraciadamente llamas `data` a uno de los parámetros de dentro, lo cual sólo lleva a confusión si eres principiante.
  Así, si quieres pasar al servidor el valor de `contenedor` y de `id`, tu parámetro `data` podría ir así:

  ```
  data:{
         data: 'AddInformacionEgreso',
         id: id,
         contenedor: contenedor
       },
  ```

  O, más claro así, para no llamar a nada `data` dentro del parámetro `data`... Las confusiones nominales son terribles a veces, sobre todo al inicio:

  ```
  data:{
         action: 'AddInformacionEgreso',
         id: id,
         contenedor: contenedor
       },
  ```
- El tipo de petición se indica con el parámetro **`type`** o **`method`** en la versiones más modernas de Ajax.
- El tipo de respuesta se indica en el parámetro **`dataType`**. Por cierto, si esperas contenido HTML, conviene poner mejor `dataType: 'html'` en vez de `dataType: 'text'`.

El problema aquí es que no estás verificando en `.php` lo que llega desde Ajax. De hecho, un mismo archivo te puede servir para procesar varias cosas, según lo que pongas en `data`.

Para verificar podrías hacer algo así. Veamos un ejemplo simple, nada más para entender el flujo:

#### `egresos/addInformacionEgreso.php`

```
<?php

    /*
       Verificas que petición hay en 
       la clave data de $_GET
    */
    $action=$_GET['data'] ?? NULL;
    
    /*
        Si es addInformacionEgreso llamamos 
        a la función AddInformacionEgreso
        De lo contrario decimos que no 
        se envió ninguna acción
    */
    if ($action==='addInformacionEgreso') {
        AddInformacionEgreso();
    } else {
        echo "<p>Ninguna acción enviada</p>";
    }
    
    /*
       Función de agregar ...
       En este archivo tú puedes tener varias funciones
       Y llamarlas según lo que recogas en $action
    */
    
    function AddInformacionEgreso(){ 
        echo "<p>Aquí el código de agregar información</p>";    
    }
```

Me he basado en la simplicidad. Si todo está bien, deberías ver este mensaje: `Aquí el código de agregar información`, de lo contrario, deberías ver: `Ninguna acción enviada`.

Cuando todo funcione, entonces pon el código que quieres ejecutar dentro de `AddInformacionEgreso()` y si requieres más datos, como un ID, un nombre, etc, debes pasarlos desde Ajax y luego recogerlos en `$_GET`.

Así, si en `data` pasas esto:

```
   data:{
          action: 'AddInformacionEgreso',
          id: id,
          contenedor: contenedor
        },
```

En `$_GET` vas a tener tres valores, cada uno asociado a su clave y podrás obtenerlos con: `$_GET['laClave']`, por ejemplo: `$_GET['action']`, `$_GET['id']`, etc ...

Comment: Perfecto!, Muchisimas gracias por todo! Ahora a probar.